# Why is css-nano (almost) not working?

Tags: node.js, css, gulp, minify

`gulp-minify-css` [says its deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify-css), and points to [gulp-css-nano](https://github.com/ben-eb/gulp-cssnano) as its successor.

**How come, I reach so much weaker results with cssnano?**

I do the minifything (and beautify afterwards for readability):

```js
gulp.task('teststyles-nano', [], function () {
    gulp.src('css/testcase.css')
    .pipe( nano() )
    .pipe( cssbeautify() )
    .pipe( rename('nano.css' ))
    .pipe( gulp.dest('./public/') );
});

gulp.task('teststyles-minify', [], function () {
    gulp.src('css/testcase.css')
    .pipe( minifyCss() )   // resp.  .pipe(minifyCss())
    .pipe( cssbeautify() )
    .pipe( rename('minify.css') )  // resp.  'minify.css'
    .pipe( gulp.dest('./public/') );
});
```

Here's my **testcase.css**, with plenty of intentional stuff to optimize:

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
    color: green;
    color: purple;  /* redundant in place */
    background-color: #caa;
}
html, body {  /* combine to above, remove duplicates? */
    margin: 0;   
    background-color: #aac;
}

/* group media queries,
   remove redundant rules and/or combine p, div */
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    p { background-color: orange; }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    p { background-color: purple; }
    div { background-color: purple; }
}

h1, h2, h3, h1, h2 { /* combine to above, remove double selectors */
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Arial, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: orange;
    text-decoration: underline;

    margin-top: 10px;  /* screams combining */
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

`minify.css` has pretty much all expected, where `nano.css` simply does not:

[image: side-by-side comparision]

I am under Windows7, x64. Versions:

```
npm list --depth=0 | grep -i css
├── css-purge@1.1.1 extraneous
├── gulp-css-purge@1.0.27
├── gulp-cssbeautify@0.1.3
├── gulp-cssnano@2.1.1
├── gulp-minify-css@1.2.3
```

Thus I am pretty clueless, on such an isolated case.

Comment: I don't think your question is really why someone decided to stop developing an open source project in his spare time so I suggest you edit the question and just ask about your specific issues with css nano.

Comment: **cssnano** doesn't do the job when it is not next to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [got feedback from the plugin author](https://github.com/ben-eb/gulp-cssnano/issues/39): These optimizations are not yet implemented.

That means, it's not about wrong parameters or use, which was basically my question. He recommends [gulp-clean-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-clean-css) as an alternative.

I think I will stick with [gulp-minify-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify-css) for a little while longer.

Answer (score 0):

Might be off point a little but I use Grunt `cssmin` which does do a great job, and the config is:-

```
    options: {
    compatibility: 'ie8',
    shorthandCompacting: false,
    roundingPrecision: -1
},
target: {
    files: [{
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'sass/',
        src: ['*.css', '!*.min.css'],
        dest: 'sass/minified',
        ext: '.min.css'
    }]
}
```